# viewpager.setCurrentItem() doesn't change to replaced item while making an infinite swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm making an infinite swipe adapter. I will try to explain as clear as I can. Please help.

**My problem**

Create a ViewPager which can swipe infinite left or right. Always create new fragment at start and end after swipe.

**My logic**

Create 5 static fragments for ViewPager.

`ORDER  0 1 2 3 4
 FRAG   a b c d e
SHOW ITEM at 2`

Each time swiping, (for eg. left) I will change position of these fragments and add new instance fragment at the end. After changing position, i set adapter item back to position center.

`OLD ORDER 0 1 2 3 4
 NEW ORDER 1 2 3 4 N
 FRAG      b c d e f
NEW SHOW ITEM at 3`

for right swipe

`OLD ORDER 0 1 2 3 4
 NEW ORDER N 0 1 2 3
 FRAG      n a b c d
NEW SHOW ITEM at 1`

I only change fragment, always set show item at position center.
I think my logic will solve for infinite swipe.

**Code**

I'll paste my code here, which using 9 fragments instead of 5. So position center is 4. I think it will help swiping more smooth.

Create list:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        Calendar tmpCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        tmpCal.add(calendarVariable, count++);
        list[i] = EachPageTransactionsFragment.newInstance(tmpCal, calendarVariable);
        if (i == 0) cal0 = tmpCal;
        if (i == 8) cal9 = tmpCal;
    }
```

Set List to Adapter and set position to center.

```
vpgMainAdapter = new ListTransactionViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity(), list, cal0, cal9);
    vpgMain.setAdapter(vpgMainAdapter);
    vpgMain.setCurrentItem(4);
```

After that, i set a listener to listen swiping.

```
vpgMain.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        private int mFocusPageA, mFocusPageB;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mFocusPageA = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (mFocusPageA != mFocusPageB) {
                    if (mFocusPageA < 5) {
                        vpgMainAdapter.addPage(-1, currentFilterStateForCalendar);
                        vpgMainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        vpgMain.setCurrentItem(4);
                        updateTitleByState(-1);
                    } else {
                        vpgMainAdapter.addPage(1, currentFilterStateForCalendar);
                        vpgMainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        vpgMain.setCurrentItem(4);
                        updateTitleByState(1);
                    }
                    mFocusPageB = mFocusPageA;
                }
                //
            }
        }
    });
```

addPage is a function which help me modify the list. Because after swipe, position will change so I set it back to center. state -1 is for swiping right, 1 for left.

addPage function

```
public void addPage(int i, int calendarVariable){
    if (i == -1){
        for (int j = 8; j > 0; j--){
            list[j] = list[j-1];
        }
        cal0.add(calendarVariable, -1);
        list[0] = EachPageTransactionsFragment.newInstance(cal0, calendarVariable);
    }else if (i == 1){
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            list[j] = list[j+1];
        }
        cal9.add(calendarVariable, 1);
        list[8] = EachPageTransactionsFragment.newInstance(cal9, calendarVariable);
    }
}
```

The problem is after i modify position items inside the list, i set viewpager.setCurrentItem(4) still the original one.

Ex:

Before: [FRAG0] [FRAG1] [FRAG2] [FRAG3] **[FRAG4]** [FRAG5] [FRAG6] [FRAG7] [FRAG8]

After change list:[FRAG1] [FRAG2] [FRAG3] [FRAG4] **[FRAG5]** [FRAG6] [FRAG7] [FRAG8] [FRAG9]

viewpager.setCurrentItem(4) => FRAG4 still shown, instead of FRAG5. Please help.

Comment: can you try to use same fragment instance , instead of creating new everytime, refresh the views on swipe of viewpager ?

Comment: If we use same fragment instance on all pages, how can it be infinite? I think problem is not about that, it is about why viewpager still get the old position fragment be.